# how to sort alphanumerical list with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I'm a beginner on JavaScript and I would ask your help for a problem:

In fact, I want to display equipments name by their number, but before the number I have alphabetical letter, for example:

```
meh10; meh120; meh20; meh614; switch12; switch130; switch20;...
```

I don't know how to sort it alphanumerically.

Comment: what you have try so far? show your html..

Comment: function sort() {
    $($('ol.toBeSorted>li').get().reverse()).each(function(outer) {
        var sorting = this;
$($('ol.toBeSorted>li').get().reverse()).each(function(inner) {
            if($('span.Node', this).text().localeCompare($('span.Node', sorting).text()) > 0) { this.parentNode.insertBefore(sorting.parentNode.removeChild(sorting), this);
            }
        });
    });
}

Comment: HTML <ol class="toBeSorted">
  {% for node in tree.iter %}
  {% if  node.attrib.for == '0' %}
<li>
  <a href="javascript:visibilite('{{node.attrib.value}}'); return
 false;"><span class="Node" title = "node" style = 'text-align : center'> {{ node.attrib.value }}</span></a>
    <div id= {{node.attrib.value}} style="display:none;">
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
  sort('il.toBeSorted>li', 'a');
</script>
</ol>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this jquery plugin:
http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try it right know and will tell you.